# Aiohttp нестабильное время задержки response на тот же самый запрос?

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Использую aiohttp в одной сессии делая 2 асинхронных запроса и 5000 раз, и отслеживаю как долго доходит ответ. Api предоставляет latency с их стороны на каждый запрос и она 5-10 ms. Примерно в 1% ответов задержка вылезает за 500мс. Можно ли что то сделать что бы ответы получал более стабильно и желательно быстрее :)?

Вот код.

```
async def fetch_url(session, u):
    async with session.get(u) as response:
        # return await response.json(loads=ujson.loads)
        return await response.json(loads=ujson.loads)

        
async def poll(url):
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(use_dns_cache=True)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
        while True:
            tasks=[]
            for x in url_all:
                tasks.append(fetch_url(session,x))
                
            results= await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() 
loop.create_task(poll(url))
loop.run_forever()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значение `latency` откуда берется? И что оно измеряет точно? Время от какого момента до какого?

Comment: Это длинна одного цикла while loop.

Comment: Нужен более точный ответ. Как именно (покажите код) меряется время?  Меряли ли время отдельных запросов? Какой размер ответа в байтах? Уверенны, что причина задержки не на стороне сервера? Если уверены, почему уверены?

Comment: Видно паттерн - каждый 100(?) запрос/цикл замедление. Что там происходит? Покажите пик поближе - как там ведет себя график. Один медленный запрос? Или несколько? Нужно мерять именно время отдельных ответов, чтоб исключить задержку именно на сервере.